# Добавить результат выражения "drive + 'A' - 1" в переменную char

Tags: c

Это должен быть один символ char (Буква тома). В зависимости от числа в переменной drive будет разный результат.

Есть вывод этого символа, но нужно его записать в переменную

```
for( drive = 1; drive <= 26; drive++ )
{
    if(!_chdrive(drive))
    {
        printf( "%c:\n", drive + 'A' - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: да буквально вот так char c = drive +'A' - 1;

Comment: Да и сам код странный - зачем в цикле сеть текущий диск?

Comment: @maint, Огромное спасибо!

Comment: @KoVadim, код украл с сайта Microsoft. И как я понял !_chdrive() работает как проверка, подключен ли данный диск. А так это обычный перебор дисков. От A до Z.